# Add some files to my android app folder

Tags: android

I am planning my android app with some files in the app folder, but i didn't figure out how to add files to my project. I don't want to use the files as resources because the user should be able to save or download more files in the same folder and i just wanted to add the basic set of files.
Can anyone help me? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use the files as resources because the user should be able to save or download more files in the same folder and i just wanted to add the basic set of files.

There is no direct means of doing this. If you package your files as assets (in `assets/`) or as raw resources, you are welcome to copy them out of your APK into internal storage on first run of your app.